# show only the date in @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.fec_ini)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I do have a view in MVC C# where I show the date using this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.fec_ini)
```

the problem is that the view shows the info 29/04/2018 12:00:00 a.m. and what I want to show is just 29/04/2018.
the property public DateTime fec_ini { get; set; } is datetime but I' not allowed to change it because it is used in other logics.

Comment: Apply a `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}"` to your `fec_ini` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Html.Raw for Display Date with format. i hope this will help you.

```
@Html.Raw(Model.fec_ini.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Comment: `@Html.Raw` is not required - `@Model.fec_ini.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` works fine.

Comment: Without Raw is also fine but we can use it for encoding it's better to use.

Comment: Only when you need to encode it - in this case its just unnecessary extra overhead :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a display template:

```
Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\DateTime.cshtml
```

With contents:

```
@{
    layout = null
}
@model DateTime
@Model.ToShortDateString()
```

This should then be picked up for all DateTime properties rendered using DisplayFor...